# Insert data in two mapped tables in spring

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 table user and userprofile mapped with each other.

In User.java getter method for userprofile is :

```
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
 public Userprofile getUserprofiles() {
    return this.userprofiles;
 }
```

and in Userprofile.java getter method for user is :

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "UserID")
 public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
 }
```

In User.jsp commandName is "userprofile", and submit method in controller is :

```
 @RequestMapping("/insertUser.do")
 public ModelAndView showLoginForm( @ModelAttribute("userprofile") Userprofile userProfileBean,BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )throws Exception
{

            java.util.Date utilDate=new java.util.Date();
            java.sql.Timestamp timest=new Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());

            userProfileBean.setEntryDate(timest);

            User user = new User();
            user.setUserProfile(userProfileBean);
            this.userServ.createUser(user);
            return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("usersMapping.do"), "Test", "Test");

}
```

When i call the insert method of user class it is inserting into user as well as userprofile table but in the userprofile table userid is not updating.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add user Profile to user

```
user.setUserProfile(userProfileBean);
```

also add user object to userProfileBean

```
userProfileBean.setUser(user);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, i was missing userProfileBean.setUser(user);